# What is the best Azure product for routing traffic between autonomic locations

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

We have a website which provides services for people based in particular city.

We want to scale and provide it for more cities but we want to remain separated IT within the city realm: one webhost, cloud service , database etc for one location. It does not only   enables us to scale individually (some cities are bigger than other several times) but most significantly it improves our code-base and db queries to not use city's predicates - despite the fact it is more expensive in general.

At the same time we do not want to use subdomain. User can switch city through dropdown and request should go to appropriate VM  without url being changed so the routing should work seamlessly.

Based on Azure documentation we are still not sure what solution would meet our needs, Traffic Manager, Load balancer or custom redirects.

Answer (score 1):

How you accomplish this is ultimately up to you, but from an Azure-specific perspective, the only multi-region built-in load-balancing service is Traffic Manager. This operates in one of three routing modes:

- Primary/failover
- Round-robin
- Closest (based on latency, not physical distance)

For any other type of routing (such as letting the user choose location, per your question), you'd need to implement this on your own or via 3rd-party service (and how to accomplish that would be a matter of opinion/debate/discussion, which is off-topic for StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking to have a separate DB, cloud-role and webhost per city, I do not see how you can get away from doing subdomains.
Do you not want subdomains because of SEO? If so, it'd be easier to find another way to solve SEO problem.

But whatever Traffic Manager or other DNS based routing solution you use, it'll be splitting users by where they come FROM and not where they're going TO.

The destination problem is solved thru separate sub-domains